# How to escape quotes inside quotes for a sink defintion for gstreamer command line

Tags: c, command-line, gstreamer, double-quotes, sink

How to I use quotes in quotes for gstreamer command line. This is gstreamer version 1.14.4 and ubuntu version 4.9.140-tegra using bash shell all running on Jetson Nano dev system.

I tried various escape methods and none worked.

The following has double quotes with quotes inside the sink definition and doesn't work.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/tom/Videos/UHD_demo_Nature.mp4 sink="glupload !  glshader fragment="\"`ca
t testfrag.frag`\"" ! glimagesinkelement"
```

I assume it's an escape sequence issue, I tried bunch of ways to escape but I would rather not bias anyone looking at this problem.  The opengl fragment is correct and works using a simple command line example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glupload ! glshader fragment="\"`cat testfrag.frag`\"" ! glimagesink
```

Any ideas is this a command shell issue or gstreamer issue I need to correct concerning double quotes.

Here is the fragment:

```
\#version 100

  #ifdef GL_ES

  precision mediump float;

  #endif

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D tex;

  uniform float time;

  uniform float width;

  uniform float height;
  vec4 myColor;


  void main () {

        myColor = texture2D( tex, v_texcoord );
        gl_FragColor = myColor;
        gl_FragColor.r = myColor.b;
        gl_FragColor.b = myColor.r;

  }
```

When I run the command line I get the following error:

```
Generates an error message:
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "100"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `%22` to escape a quotationmark?

[This](https://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/) site shows the html encodings, I got that idea from this line:

> The query string for the new URI with '&' separating query elements. Elements containing '&' characters should encode them as "%26".

from [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gsturihandler.html?gi-language=c#GstUri) website.